# how can i make my guessing color game work in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have made a simple guessing color game.
The aim of the game is to try and guess the color that has been entered by game master.

I was wondering how to loop it, so that you were allowed a number of guesses, to guess what the game master entered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
print"THIS IS GUESSING GAME""\n"
print"WELCOME""\n"

rsplay = "Q"

print"Game master, enter the colour that you want:"
colour1 = raw_input("")
colour2 = raw_input("")
colour3 = raw_input("")
colour4 = raw_input("")

print"colour set!""\n"
num_guess = raw_input("Set the number of guess:")

print ("\n" * 50)

playername = raw_input("Enter Your Name: ")

   print "Hello" ,playername, "!" "\n" "You have<",num_guess, ">guesses to                  `enter the colors correctly in the order as" "\n" "how it being entered. Let's     play."`

   trial = 0
   x = 0
   y = 0

   print"Enter guess number" ,trial, ":"
   guess1 = raw_input("")
   guess2 = raw_input("")
   guess3 = raw_input("")
   guess4 = raw_input("")



    while trial < num_guess:
         trial = trial + 1

if (guess1 == colour1):
 x = x + 1
else :
    if (guess2 == colour2):
     x = x + 1
    else :
        if (guess3 == colour3):
          x = x + 1
        else :
            if (guess4 == colour4):
              x = x + 1
            else:
                if (guess1 == colour2):
                    y = y + 1
                else :
                    if (guess1 == colour3):
                        y = y + 1
                    else :
                        if (guess1 == colour4):
                            y = y + 1
                        else :
                            if (guess2 == colour1):
                                y = y + 1
                            else :
                                if (guess2 == colour3):
                                    y = y + 1
                                else :
                                    if (guess2 == colour4):
                                        y = y + 1
                                    else :
                                        if (guess3 == colour1):
                                            y = y + 1
                                        else :
                                            if (guess3 == colour2):
                                                y = y + 1
                                            else :
                                                if (guess3 == colour4):
                                                    y = y + 1
                                                else :
                                                    if (guess4 == colour1):
                                                        y = y + 1
                                                    else :
                                                        if (guess4 == colour2):
                                                            y = y + 1
                                                        else :
                                                            if (guess4 == colour3):
                                                                y = y + 1
                                                            else:
                                                                     print "You have" ,x, "CORRECT and" ,y, "MISSED" "\n"



 print "You've won! Well done",playername,"! You Did it in",trial,"guesses." "\n"

 print "Do You want to play again ?",rsplay,"\n"
 if(rsplay == "Q"):
print "Bye..."
else :
if (rsplay == "P"):
    print "Play Again"
```

Comment: Write a separate script just to understand looping. Hard-code all the variables you need so you can quickly run it. Dump everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You set:

```
num_guess = raw_input("Set the number of guess:")
```

Then you can do:

```
while num_guess > 0:
    guess = raw_input("")
    # game logic goes here
    num_guess = num_guess - 1
```

Then the user will have exactly `num_guess` guesses, and you can keep count of how many correct guesses the user has made by setting `count = 0` before the `while`, and incrementing (`count = count + 1`) it each time the user guesses correctly. In this case the number of *wrong* guesses will surely be the total number of guesses minus the correct ones (`count`).

As an added bonus, all your `if` statements will be much shorter since you won't have 4 variables for 4 guesses.